# Keyboard resetting on log in

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, login

I recently switched to the Colemak layout after a fresh install of 11.10. Now, whenever I log in, the keyboard is set to QWERTY (USA), which is very confusing. How do I make it so that only Colemak is the only layout used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on OpenBSD now so my Ubuntu-specific knowledge might be a bit off, but you can do what I did (I'm also a Colemak convert) for Ubuntu.

For console, add

```
loadkeys colemak
```

(or it might be)

```
loadkeys linux_console/colemak.iso15.kmap
```

to  /etc/init.d/local

Refer to the [RcLocal Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto) to set up rc.local for Ubuntu
and the Colemak [Linux/Unix page](http://colemak.com/Unix) for additional console and Xorg configuration info.

You can set the Colemak Layout from GDM (at the bottom) and from System/Preferences/Keyboard when logged in

Comment: there's no way to switch the keyboard layout on the login screen any more. I'll have to look into the other suggestions tomorrow. thanks for the answer regardless.

Comment: oh no. i didn't know they changed that, too. might have to modify/actually make the xorg.conf to get colemak system-wide.

Comment: `Option  “XkbRules” “xorg”

Option  “XkbModel” “pc105″

Option  “XkbLayout” “us”

Option  “XkbVariant” “colemak”`

Comment: where can i put that? there's no xorg.conf any more either. :-P

Comment: you can either run X -configure or do it the "new way" by making an [xorg.conf "snippet"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) and placing it in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, my keyboard disposition was switching to qwerty every time I boot. Open a terminal and type the command:

```
ibus-setup
```

A window will appear, in the advanced section, select:

```
Use system keyboard disposition
```

Comment: @andrew-46: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/716173/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**